# Find German Telefone numbers with Selenium (Java)

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, web-crawler

I am trying to get the Telefon numbers (german format)  from german websites via a regex with Selenium Web driver API. My problem is that I get some false positives, which I am not able to exclude yet. Could somebody help me optimize the regex? So that I know for sure that what I have got is 100% a telefone number. In the code, Impressum is generally the name for contact details, this is why i am looking for this word "Impressum" on a website and then click on it and afterwards download the html body in a string. Then I am using regex to look for telefone numbers in the html body. Thank you.

```
  public void search() {
        jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        WebElement w = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("mpress"));
        if (w.getText().matches("Impressum" ) || w.getText().matches("impressum")){
            w.click();
        }
        impressum.setBody(driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText());   // HTML-body download
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")
    public void TelRegex() {
        final String regex = "([\\+][0-9]{1,3} [ \\.\\-\\/])?  ([\\(][0-9]{1,6}[\\)])?  ([0-9 \\.\\-\\/]{10,20})$";
        final String string = impressum.getBody();

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
```

In the code, Impressum is generally the name for contact details, this is why i am looking for this word "Impressum" on a website and then click on it and afterwards download the html body in a string. Then I am using regex to look for telefone numbers in the html body. It gives me fone numbers but sometimes there are also other numbers which are not fone numbers.

Comment: Please share URL or html source code.

Comment: Here is the URL which I am opening: https://www.vario-doser.de

Answer (score 0):

Class:

```
package syed;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Syed {
    private static WebDriver driver;    

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {       
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\selenium-tests\\GCH_driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\pburgr\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();        
    }
    @Before public void setUp() {} @After public void tearDown() {}
    @AfterClass public static void tearDownClass() {
        driver.quit();
    }
    @Test
    public void extractAllPhoneNumbers() {
        ArrayList<String> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();

        driver.get("https://www.vario-doser.de/");
        WebElement impressumLink = waitSec(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@href='ueber-uns/impressum/']")));
        impressumLink.click();
        WebElement content = waitSec(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("content")));
        String[] contentText = content.getText().split("\\n");

        for (String line: contentText) {
            if (line.length() > 0 && Objects.equals(line.substring(0, 3), "Tel")) {
                phoneNumbers.add(line);
                System.out.println("Extracting: " + line);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'");
            }
        }
        if (phoneNumbers.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Extracted phone numbers:");
            for (String phoneNumber: phoneNumbers) {
                System.out.println(phoneNumber);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No phone number found.");
        }

    }   
    public WebDriverWait waitSec(WebDriver driver, int sec) {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, sec);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5) on port 3253
Only local connections are allowed.
Dub 15, 2019 9:46:23 DOP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Extracting: Tel.: 09721 / 533404
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Extracting: Tel: 0180 / 60 05 85 0
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Textline does not beginn with 'Tel'
Extracted phone numbers:
Tel.: 09721 / 533404
Tel: 0180 / 60 05 85 0
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: no, this is not what I am looking for. Because in this case only those fone numbers will be downloaded which starts with a string "Tel" followed by the number but I want to download all formats which are available for german phone numbers, so that every fone number gets downloaded - not matter in which format it is written. Do you get my point?

Answer (score 0):

Extracting phone number based on prefixes:

```
public void extractAllPhoneNumbers() {
    ArrayList<String> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    driver.get("https://www.vario-doser.de/");
    WebElement impressumLink = waitSec(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@href='ueber-uns/impressum/']")));
    impressumLink.click();
    WebElement content = waitSec(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("content")));
    String[] contentText = content.getText().split("\\n");

    String[] prefixes = {"0180 / ", "09721 / "};

    for (String line: contentText) {
        for (String prefix: prefixes) {
            if (line.contains(prefix)) {
                phoneNumbers.add(line);
                System.out.println("Extracting: " + line.split(prefix)[1]);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Textline does not contain any of the prefixes.");
            }
        }
    }
    if (phoneNumbers.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Extracted phone numbers:");
        for (String phoneNumber: phoneNumbers) {
            System.out.println(phoneNumber);
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No phone number found.");
    }

}
```

But it includes Fax.

```
...
Textline does not contain any of the prefixes.
Extracted phone numbers:
Tel.: 09721 / 533404
Fax: 09721 / 533405
Tel: 0180 / 60 05 85 0
```